# Deriving the Helmholtz equation in polar form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The two dimensional helmholtz equation is $$\frac{\partial ^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2}+k^2 \phi=0$$
and I have that $$\nabla^2 u(r,\theta)=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}$$

How can I derive the helmholstz equation in polar coordinates from this information?

Comment: $\frac{\partial ^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2}+k^2 \phi$ is not quite an equation!  Perhaps you meant to write $\frac{\partial ^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2}+k^2 \phi = 0$? Cheers!

Comment: @ yes I did mean to write it equal to zero. sorry!

Comment: Well, ***now*** it is an equation!  Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helmholtz in cartesian coordinates being

$\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2} + k^2 \phi = 0, \tag{1}$

we recall that

$\nabla^2 \phi = \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2}; \tag{2}$

since

$\nabla^2 u(r,\theta)=\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2} \tag{3}$

is a general expression for $\nabla^2$ in polars, valid for *any* function $u$, we have the polar expression for $\nabla^2 \phi$:

$\nabla^2 \phi(r,\theta)=\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \theta^2}; \tag{4}$

(1) then becomes

$\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \theta^2} + k^2 \phi = 0.  \tag{5}$

Pretty simple, no?